# USB device is plugged in, but how to make it active?

Tags: linux, usb, audio

I have a Razer headset plugged in. Everytime I restart the computer I have to unplug/plug the headset to make it work.

It even shows up the system:

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1532:001b Razer USA, Ltd
```

It does not show up as a valid sound device in **system -> preferences -> sound**.

Does anyone know how I can make the headset "active" without replugging it to the computer?

```
uname -a
Linux unix 2.6.35-28-generic-pae #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 20:43:15 
UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

> Use:
>
> `/etc/modprobe.conf.local`
>
> add "alias modulename" depending on the driver name; use an editor as root.

If you have the same problem after resume try this:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7257049&postcount=2

The example talks about a wireless driver but essentially you're reloading a module automatically after sleep.

If your device isn't using a driver, try by restarting the sound driver.

Comment: but ChrisAD's original post says that it does work ... if you plug it in *after* turning on the PC.

Comment: @CarlF, My bad, edited answer